# Reference request: Oldest books on algebraic curves with unsolved exercises?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, textbook-recommendation

Per the title, what are some of the oldest books on algebraic curves out there with unsolved exercises? Maybe there are some hidden gems from before the 20th century out there.

Comment: I have the impression that exercises started to appear on research level books not too long ago, say the 60s or even the 70s...

Comment: @IMeasy there are exercises in all Bourbaki books, the first volumes of which appeared in the 1940's.

Comment: Same question by OP on [calculus, real analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313808/),[linear algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313967/), [complex analysis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324717/), [non-analytic geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326104/), [number theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327697/).

Comment: Very confused as to the point of these questions. Is the OP writing an article on the subject or something?

Comment: @SamHopkins I'm not. For my edification and those of others. The assumed hostility has to do with the unfortunate presentist anti-antiquarian attitude of younger blogosphere mathematicians active on MO. Most well-known senior mathematicians I have talked to in real life about these questions have been quite receptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeuthen’s *Lehrbuch der abzählenden Methoden der Geometrie* ([1914](//zbmath.org/?q=an:45.0799.01)) has *Übungsaufgaben* at the end of most sections (§§35, 48, 54, 59, 92, 97, 115, 141, 157, 166, 178, 185, 205).

Magnus’ *Sammlung von Aufgaben und Lehrsätzen aus der analytischen Geometrie* ([1833, 1837](//gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/volumes/id/PPN585370141)) has chapters on *Linien höherer Grade* (Vol. 3, pp. 241–292) and *Flächen höherer Grade* (Vol. 4, pp. 377–425).

Comment: @user126532 You might generally like [this search](//emis.de/cgi-bin/jfmen/MATH/JFM/full.html?type=html&format=short&ti=Sammlung+Aufgaben), which produces e.g. Minin ([1911](//zbmath.org/?q=an:42.0547.01)) incl. *Aufgaben der algebraischen Geometrie*.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the works of [George Salmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Salmon) (1819-1903) interesting.

Amongst others, he wrote:

- [A treatise on higher planes curves](https://archive.org/details/3edtreatiseonhighesalmuoft/page/n6) (1852)

[Here](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Salmon.html) is his MacTutor bio.